# How to make flex child to have width 100% of it's parent's parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex child, inside a scrollable flex column. I want it to set its width to 100% of the scrollable flex column's parent.

It's because I want to have a notifications bar, and it automatically opens if a new notification arrives, and currently the contents of the scrollable flex are jumping around (every item is flex).

Let me demonstrate:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}
.row {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.col {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.target-width {
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.scrollable {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
.content {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.notifications {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='row target-width'>
  <div class='col scrollable'>
    <div class='col content'>content</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='col notifications'></div>
</div>
```

At the above example I would expect `content` to have width of `500px`, even though its direct parent `scrollable` has a width of `300px`.

Let's assume that every width, and height is unknown, the above are just for demonstration. So all we know is we want to set `content`'s width as width of `target-width`. Not knowing exactly the width of `target-width`, is there a way to make that work?

Comment: Hi! "target-width" is the parent of "scrollable" and "notifications". So it's width is divided by these two children. I didn't understood exactly the problem: You want that "scrollable" to have full width of "target-width" ?

Comment: And the `content` have the width of his parent, `scrollable`. And I explained above why it have that width.

Comment: *I don't have enough reputation to comment.* Now the "content" and the "notification bar" are flexible elements within a flexible container. "content" and "notification bar" are at the same level and "content" uses the space left by "notification bar" (flexible base: 200px;). Do you want to get this result, or do you want "notification bar" with a width of 200px to be displayed above "content" with the width of 100% of the container?

Comment: Are you saying you want `.content` to overlap the notifications column? It's a child of an item in a flex row that includes notifications, so it will never overlap unless you use absolute positioning.

Comment: Not with CSS & flexbox only. You could use JavaScript to set a non-relative width, when you know it.

Comment: I want `scrollable` to have the width it can take. `target-width.width - notifications.width`. I want `content` to have width of `target-width`. Imagine instead of being unable to see what's under notifications (if it would be absolute), you can see it if you scroll on x axis. I couldn't explain it better.

Comment: @GergőHorváth you want it to scroll horizontally?

Comment: @inorganik yes.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your need and I'm not really sure if it can be done only with css.

Here is a JS code that can solve your problem. Please keep in mind that my solution maybe is not the best one, but I think It's a starting point.

Put this code into Head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setContentWidth() {
      var elementTW = document.querySelector('.target-width');
      var styleTW = window.getComputedStyle(elementTW);
      var widthTW = styleTW.width;

      document.querySelector(".content").setAttribute("style","width:" + parseInt(widthTW) +"px" );
    }
    window.onload = setContentWidth;
</script>
```

Edited my answer to fit the question. Now `content` receive the parent width.

Tell me if this solve your problem or you need further assistance.

Comment: It could solve the problem, but I was looking for a CSS solution.

Comment: Then I don't know a solution only with CSS. Maybe if you're using sass you can have something like this:
`$width:100px;

.target-width{
  width: $width;
}

.content{
 width: $width;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the solution to what you are looking for. I have applied some changes to the code to reproduce what I think I understand you want to achieve. Could you review it and tell me if it is the result you are looking for?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.col {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.target-width {
  /*width:500px;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position:relative;
}
.scrollable {
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  flex: 1;
  
}
.content {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100vw;  
  height: 100%;
}
.notifications {
  background: blue;
  opacity:.5;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class='row target-width'>
  <div class='col scrollable'>
    <div class='col content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent aliquam quis erat ut rhoncus. Nunc non sollicitudin eros. Vivamus sollicitudin, orci vitae congue rutrum, lacus nulla blandit dolor, nec egestas est est eu est. Donec mi metus, tempor quis ante quis, viverra ornare nulla. Aliquam fringilla pharetra nisi, ac bibendum tortor rhoncus auctor. Sed quam elit, finibus vel dignissim rhoncus, viverra ut risus. Sed placerat, massa et vehicula feugiat, ex augue pulvinar tortor, eget sodales sem libero non metus. Fusce laoreet sollicitudin erat a posuere. Mauris at sem metus. Sed posuere quam bibendum malesuada auctor. Ut pulvinar eros quis massa molestie, sed tempus urna ultrices. Vivamus arcu turpis, porta ut vehicula at, dapibus vitae massa.

Nulla facilisi. Curabitur a dignissim purus. Morbi rhoncus sit amet mauris sed viverra. Sed eget justo eget dui commodo vehicula. Pellentesque convallis ultricies quam, ac maximus purus mollis vitae. Nam ut erat erat. Ut ultrices quam magna, vel efficitur massa finibus nec. Maecenas turpis tellus, tempus ut iaculis quis, elementum rhoncus nunc. Quisque egestas condimentum nunc, non feugiat erat malesuada eu. Donec in justo ullamcorper, molestie justo ac, elementum leo. Morbi ultricies et sapien sit amet bibendum. Sed ornare eget lectus vel tempor. Suspendisse sodales ipsum in tincidunt dictum. Duis placerat ligula ac sem imperdiet sollicitudin.

Pellentesque ex risus, rutrum vel mi sed, egestas faucibus nisl. Mauris rutrum sem justo, eget posuere neque aliquam non. Sed molestie neque mauris, quis gravida turpis rutrum eget. Duis eu mauris vitae arcu suscipit sagittis. Duis aliquam tortor quis massa placerat vestibulum. Fusce eu purus non eros ornare aliquam a accumsan turpis. Maecenas eu nunc dignissim, ornare diam et, malesuada est.

Donec eu commodo libero. Donec fermentum metus in quam lobortis, ut eleifend felis posuere. Donec sed leo malesuada, viverra tellus sit amet, egestas leo. Cras tempus, ex et tincidunt varius, magna mauris dignissim ex, in mattis dui erat eu arcu. Praesent tristique faucibus massa eget malesuada. Aliquam vitae enim quam. Phasellus maximus ullamcorper leo, auctor luctus ipsum volutpat quis. Ut nec neque non felis bibendum ultricies. Cras leo odio, condimentum et eros at, feugiat lacinia sem. Sed odio sem, lobortis sed enim vitae, bibendum faucibus velit. Ut eget diam consequat, imperdiet sem at, hendrerit ligula. Mauris egestas consequat magna, gravida fermentum leo malesuada pellentesque. Sed non pellentesque purus, at congue arcu.<br/></div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class='col notifications'>
    
  </div>
</div>
```